# Visual Studio Mac version control pull fails with error 128

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-mac

I had been using Git version control to push changes from my VS Windows to VS Mac for months when suddenly the VS Mac would give me an error 128 (Git failed with a fatal error.  ExitCode : 128).  Sometimes instead it would first ask me to login to Git but even after providing my Git credentials it would give me the error 128 again.  Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to install Git Desktop for macOS (https://desktop.github.com/).  Now that I am using this app to pull my changes (Fetch origin) I like the workflow and I may just stick with it.